# Xamarin.Forms Application.Current.Properties retained on application upgrade?

Tags: xamarin.forms, settings

We're using Application.Current.Properties to store settings data for our app.

When we release a new version of the app to the store (Apple App Store and Google Play), are these settings retained or cleared?

Answer (score 4):

I've just run a test by distributing two versions to HockeyApp - both for iOS and Android - and the values stored in ***Application.Current.Properties*** (note, not ***Settings*** from any settings plugin) ***are*** retained on installation of the updated version.

This is good news for us and our customer!

Answer (score 0):

See [this](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/96283/#Comment_96283) thread in the Xamarin Forums

> No, all values in the name-value dictionary are serialized to disk every time when the application goes to sleep. They are read back when the application is loaded again.

The data of your app is - generally speaking - not cleared when you install an update (it *is* deleted when the app is uninstalled), cf. [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/28541), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7277797/2249175) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16113604/clear-data-on-update). Hence `App.Current.Properties` should be maintained when updating an app. But you can easily try it. Publish a beta on HockeyApp, TesFlight or whatever, update the app and see what happens.

Comment: Thanks - that's what I thought. Our live app is hard to test via HockeyApp (due to customer's infrastructure requirements). I'll create a small test app and try it via HockeyApp.